# Python Azure Service Bus Not retrieving messages from queue

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

Im trying to use python azure service bus client to constantly check a queue for new messages that contains process Id. For some reason, everytime i initialize the azure service bus client it runs for a couple of seconds then output the following message: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

. Ive double checked my queue names and everything but I cannot understand what the issue is.

```
with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver( queue_name=CALC_REQUEST_QUEUE)
    print( "state 1" )
    with receiver:
        print("state")
        for msg in receiver:
            calc_request = json.loads( str( msg ) )
            processing_identifier = calc_request.get( 'processingIdentifier', None )
            print( "Received: " + str( processing_identifier ) )
            calc_config = fetch_calc_configuration( processing_identifier )
            calc_response = invoke_capsule_summary_processing(calc_config)
```

Comment: I'm wondering what if you just receive and print out the message? such that we could locate whether it's an issue related to the receiving part or to the following processing part.

Comment: @AdamLing I went with your suggestion. I tried to just receive and print out the message but had no luck. The code errors out before it gets an opportunity to print out the message. I believe it's a problem receiving the message.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's the content of the message that triggers the error -- what's  the content of the message you send and are they sent via the same SDK?

feel free to open an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pull new messages from some queue continuously,try This :

```
import asyncio
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
from azure.servicebus.aio import ServiceBusClient

CONNECTION_STR = ''
QUEUE_NAME = ''


async def main():
    servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)

    async with servicebus_client:
        receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
        async with receiver:
            received_msgs = await receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
            for msg in received_msgs:
                print(str(msg))
                await receiver.complete_message(msg)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
while True : 
    #each 10 seconds to pull messages from queue.
    sleep(10)  
    print('pull messages...')
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Result:
[image]